# SDE connections to geodatabase as schema owners not working properly

Tags: arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase

An enterprise GDB that was working fine seems to have gone wrong somewhere. When I connect to it as the system admin from ArcGIS Pro, I can see all the spatial data that is stored in the SQL Server database properly (vector layer as vector, raster layer as raster). However, when I connect to it as a schema owner (no matter which one), data cannot be seen properly. A bit convoluted to explain, but basically I would say that, when connected as a schema owner:

- Raster tables are seen as vector layers (a polygon with the extent of the raster).
- Vector layers seem to be recognized properly though (and displayed).
- I can't load raster files to the GDB.
- If I right click on the connection as a schema owner I can see that "Geodatabase Connection Properties" is greyed out (when I connect as SA, it is NOT greyed out).

I highlight this thing about the "Geodatabase Connection Properties" because I have another Enterprise GDB that doesn't have any problems, and when doing right click as a schema owner, "Geodatabase Connection Properties" is NOT greyed out.

User login name is the same as schema.

-> SQL Server 11.0.2100.60

-> SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

-> ArcGIS Pro 2.6.1

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to specify the RDBMS in use (with exact release) and the exact release of Pro. Details on the exact version of geodatabase in the two instances would be useful.

Comment: Thanks. Information added.

Comment: Which user owns the tables? Is the login name the same as the schema? Please [Edit] the Question.

Comment: Vince, I'm rather new on Enterprise GDB. How can I check the table owner? All I know is that it was loaded into the GDB by the schema owner (when the GDB was working fine. Now it's not possible to load data as a schema owner).

Comment: I can't walk you through a checklist of things to try. This is an issue best handled by Tech Support.

Comment: User login name is the same as the schema. Question edited.

Comment: I don't have tech support. I wouldn't try here otherwise. But thanks anyway.

Comment: If you have a current license, you either have Tech Support or access to someone with Tech Support. You need to be able to report what is different and what has changed (the DBA will likely need to be involved).